# shopify liquid: How does "form.posted_successfully?" work?

Tags: forms, shopify, liquid

I was reading this [page](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/forms/add-fields-to-your-contact-form#find-where-to-add-custom-fields-in-the-code) and came across this code:

```
    {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
      <p class="quote">{{ 'contact.form.post_success' | t }}</p>
    {% endif %}
```

What I don't understand is, as a server-side language, how does liquid know whether the form is submitted successfully or not?

Comment: _"as a server-side language, how does liquid know"_ um, doesn't the form get submitted to the same server? What do you mean by "as a server-side language"?  But yes, it uses GET parameter as explained. In fact, you can attach it to the URL and it will behave as though you _had_ submitted the form (but not as though you're submitting now). 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GET attribute that is applied to the page URL that is set to true if the form is successfully submitted -> `?contact_posted=true`.

If that GET attribute is present in the URL address the if statement becomes `true` and it will show the success message.

Comment: For newsletter subscription form, it is `?customer_posted=true`

Comment: How do I make "customer_posted" go away on refresh?

Comment: @SanjivPradhanang https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/